# How can I change the value in a scheduled task with Java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, scheduled-tasks

**PingInvoker.java**

```
@Service
 public class PingInvoker
 {
   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000) //<--how can I make this changeable while server is up and running
   public void ping()
   {
     List<Server> svr = Manager.geList();

     System.out.println("Invoking " + svr.size() + " Ping(s)");

     for (Server i : svr)
       i.ping();

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The scheduler annotations are just a lightweight convenience for the simplest use cases. If you need access to more flexibility, such as runtime re-scheduling of tasks, then you need to use a different technique.

In your case, it should be sufficient to `@Autowire` a `TaskScheduler` field in your class, which you can then use to dynamically schedule your tasks. See the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler) for more info.